# single function in javascript called multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In the below code i'm running a loop. Within that I have 4 links and also I have written an onclick event. If I click on particular link by having the user_id it will get into function `myFunction` and from there i'm calling function `refreshId(session_to_user)`. For the first time click event it is working fine. If I click on another link two other functions start running vice versa.

My requirement is according to the link which I click the function `refreshId(session_to_user)` should work. While clicking the first it should work only for my first user_id. If I clicked the second link the first user_id should be suspended only the second link user_id should be used. Please help me.

```html
for loop() 
{
    <a id='some' name='some' onclick='myFunction(".$result['user_id'].")'></a>
}
```

```js
function refreshId(session_to_user) {                                           
    setInterval(function()
        $('.chat-box').load("<?php echo base_url()."users/message/refresh_div/"; ?>" + session_to_user);
    }, 10000);
}

function myFunction(user_id) { 
    var session_to_user = user_id; 
    refreshId(session_to_user); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clear the interval on each call:-

```
var interval;
function refreshId(session_to_user) {                                           

    if(interval)
       clearInterval(interval);

    interval = setInterval(function()
        $('.chat-box').load("<?php echo base_url()."users/message/refresh_div/"; ?>" + session_to_user);
    }, 10000);
}
```